# ¿Existe un equivalente español al 'Uncle Joke' para quien cuenta chistes malos?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, español-neutral

En estos días, viendo dibujos animados en idioma inglés sin subtítulos, hacían referencia al término *Uncle Joke* respecto a un personaje que contaba chistes malos. No quise cambiar el SAP (de inglés a español) pues suele primar una traducción muy mexicanista ante algunos términos de un corte particular. ¿Alguien me puede colaborar con una traducción en un español 'neutro'? (cosa compleja...)

Comment: Sería mejor que incluyeras un enlace.  Con youtube, puedes crear un enlace que da el momento correcto de inicio de la escena en cuestión (timestamp).

Comment: Yo lo había oído como "dad's jokes". Buscando en google: [29 Dad Jokes That Are So Bad They're Actually Good](https://www.buzzfeed.com/mikespohr/29-dad-jokes-that-are-so-bad-their-actually-good?utm_term=.pvRAMWyWA5#.vwW8KJBJ8g), [124 Dad Jokes that Will Make You Laugh or Cringe](https://www.livin3.com/100-bad-dad-jokes-that-will-make-you-laugh-or-cringe), [dad's jokes en Reddit]{https://www.reddit.com/r/dadjokes/)

Comment: En Colombia se diría: "Un chiste flojo". No lo agrego como respuesta porque no sé que tan neutral sea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que el "uncle joke" es **el chiste que no es chistoso**, contado por el tío.  O sea, "uncle joke" no se refiere a la persona que cuenta los **malos chistes**.  En tu pregunta me dio la impresión de que quizás lo entendías al revés, pero no sé si estoy en lo cierto.

Otras opciones:

> Todo el mundo tiene un amigo que siempre se quiere hacer el gracioso pero no le sale. El comediante y actor argentino Joaquín Castellano compartió en su cuenta de Facebook un video escenificando a ese amigo que cuenta **malos chistes**.
>
> Tal como se aprecia en la reproducción de Facebook, el joven argentino suele reírse de **frases sin sentido** o **que no son graciosas**. Además, intenta hacer reír a sus amigos con **bromas que no causan gracia**. *http://locoslocoslocoslocos.blogspot.com/2016/06/tienes-un-amigo-que-cuenta-chistes.html*

Comment: Una definición informal de Uncle Jock se puede encontrar [acá](https://definithing.com/uncle-joke/): "uncle jokes are jokes that have zero intelligence or wit behind them and are often told by uncles at family events"

Comment: tienes razón @aparente001 , el contexto del dibujo me llevó a malinterpretar el término.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en donde lo viste fue en Teen Titans Go, porque Chico Bestia, Star Fire y Cyborg le dicen Plomo a Robin por contar malos chistes pero en la pantalla escriben "Uncle Jokes", también me lo preguntaba, pero me imagino que se refiere a que hace chistes sin gracia, tipo gente adulta que se ríe de cosas que no causan gracia a los más jovenes

Comment: Decirle a alguien que es un "plomo" es decirle que es un pesado. Esa traducción en la serie refleja los problemas de traducir "uncle joke". Uno puede ser un plomo/pesado por muchas cosas, no solo por contar chistes malos.